# Настройка отображения блоков

Tags: html, css

Цель: Мне нужно чтобы блоки красиво и ровно размещались внутри родительского. Как на скриншоте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я же имею ситуацию где блоки растягивают родительский по высоте и не умещаются друг с другом как будто им не хватает ширины.

```
.left-box 
float: left;
width: 35%;
text-align: left;
max-width: 100%;

.left-box.profile-details 
width: 49%;
float: none;

.column2
float: right;
clear: right;
width: 49%;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Единственный вариант сейчас для меня добиться нужного мне отображения это поменять left-box details profile-details и column2 местами в html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в этом случае в мобильной версии блоки смешиваются друг с другом, а мне хотелось бы настроить css, чтобы отображалось ровно и не нужно было ничего менять в html.

Благодарю душевно за любые попытки помочь :)

Comment: Можно весь код в студию?

Comment: Почему вы не используете `flex`?

Comment: Код не мой, я лишь пытаюсь его изменить, чтобы выглядело так как мне надо.

Весь код каждого блока или какого-то конкретного?

Flex можно использовать чтобы в мобильной версии блоки шли друг за другом, но хотелось сделать это без flex.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к каждому блоку свойство `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Не помогло, всё равно блоки съезжают